# how to get the Long count value in for each loop from the outside the loop

Tags: java, hibernate, java-server

crashService:

```
            for (CrashReportForChartForm crashReport : crashReportForChartForms) {
                //i want to get this count value and send it to else part below 
                Long count = crashReport.getCount();
                Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(crashReport.getAddedDate());
                dates.add(newDate);
            }

            for (LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
                // convert local date to date format
                Date accdate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);

                DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
                String addDate = date.format(format);
                if (!dates.contains(accdate)) {
                    resultCrashReportForChartForms.add(new CrashReportForChartForm(addDate, new Long(0)));
                } else {
                    //count value should be get from count in crashReport
                    resultCrashReportForChartForms.add(newCrashReportForChartForm(addDate, count));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultCrashReportForChartForms; 
}
```

Comment: Simply declare `Long count` outside of the `for` loop. That's simply a problem of scope (and indentation hiding the problem).

Comment: i just want to get crashReport.getCount() from for each loop and send it to resultCrashReportForChartForms.add(newCrashReportForChartForm(addDate,crashReport.getCount()));

Comment: I think from your code it seems like you want to calculating the crashcount for all days over a particular range. There are couple of things which are ambiguous :
a. else part of the code containing a for loop. 
b. Also assuming that there will be only one crashReport per day.

Comment: i removed the for loop in else part   
i just want to get crashReport.getCount() from for each loop and send it to resultCrashReportForChartForms.add(newCrashReportForChartFor‌​m(addDate,crashRepor‌​t.getCount()));

Comment: I took the liberty to indent your code a bit better (please do it yourself next time). You can see you declare the variable (= `Long count`) inside the first loop, meaning it only existing in the loop. Simply declare it outside the loop, set the value in the loop (like you do now) and that fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Date,Integer> crashCounts = new HashMap<>();
long count;
for (CrashReportForChartForm crashReport : crashReportForChartForms) {
     Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(crashReport.getAddedDate());
     if(crashCounts.containsKey(newDate)){
     count=crashCounts.get(newDate)+ crashReport.getCount();
     crashCounts.put(newDate,count);
   }
    else{
       crashCounts.put(newDate,crashReport.getCount());
    }
}
```

This will give you the list of crash for particular days. Post this you can run a for loop to check if for a particular date contains no crashes. If there is no crash you can add a dummy record containing a crash count 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map<Date,Long>`:

```
            Map<Date,Long> dateCount = new HashMap<>();
            for (CrashReportForChartForm crashReport : crashReportForChartForms) {
                //i want to get this count value and send it to else part below 
                Long count = crashReport.getCount();
                Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(crashReport.getAddedDate());
                dateCount.put(newDate, count);
            }

            for (LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
                // convert local date to date format
                Date accdate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);

                DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
                String addDate = date.format(format);
                Long count = dateCount.get(accdate);
                if (count == null) {
                    resultCrashReportForChartForms.add(new CrashReportForChartForm(addDate, new Long(0)));
                } else {
                    //count value should be get from count in crashReport
                    resultCrashReportForChartForms.add(newCrashReportForChartForm(addDate, count));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultCrashReportForChartForms; 
}
```

UPDATE:

To cumulate the count per date:

```
            Map<Date,Long> dateCount = new HashMap<>();
            for (CrashReportForChartForm crashReport : crashReportForChartForms) {
                //i want to get this count value and send it to else part below 
                Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(crashReport.getAddedDate());
                Long count = dateCount.get(newDate);
                if (count == null) {
                    count = crashReport.getCount();
                } else {
                    count += crashReport.getCount();
                }
                dateCount.put(newDate, count);
            }
```

UPDATE 2:

Note that in the second loop, accdate is actually a java.sql.Date, and I'm not sure it can be used as is to retrieve the count from the map.